# using pgrep substitution with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a mongod instance running on "HOST" and "PORT", and I'm trying to get the ulimit parameters of the process over ssh.

So the following two command works fine.

```
// outputs pid of mongod
ssh HOST@PORT pgrep mongod
17215

// outputs ulimit parameters of the process
ssh HOST@PORT cat proc/17215/limits
Limit            Soft Limit      Hard Limit     Units
Max cpu time     ...
```

So I thought putting $(pgrep mongod) instead of the hard coded value would work too, but it doesn't.

```
ssh HOST@PORT cat proc/$(pgrep mongod)/limits
> cat proc/26394/limits: No such file or directory
```

Actually there is another mongod running on localhost port 26394. It seems like $(pgrep mongod) outputs local mongod's pid, instead of the remote one. How can I change the last command to get the desired output?

As a side note, I would like to do it one command line (not like, ssh HOST@PORT; and then cat proc/$(pgrep mongod)/limits).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ssh HOST@PORT 'cat proc/$(pgrep mongod)/limits'
```

That will avoid a local shell interpolation of `$(pgrep mongod)`, forcing that `pgrep` to be executed on the remote server.